# Error: Request unsafe for browser client domain: dialogflow.googleapis.com

Tags: node.js, express, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm setting up a *DialogFlow wrapper* and I'm using the *DialogFlow JavaScript SDK*. But, I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Request unsafe for browser client domain:
>   dialogflow.googleapis.com

This was working before, but I'm not sure why it suddenly stopped working.

I've tried reverting all code to a version that worked. I'm sure it's a DialogFlow error.

```
  const intentDetectResponse = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request)
```

The complete error log is as follows:

```
{ Error: Request unsafe for browser client domain: dialogflow.googleapis.com
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/Users/NewProject/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:101:45)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/NewProject/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:70:11)
  code: 3,
  details:
   'Request unsafe for browser client domain: dialogflow.googleapis.com',
  metadata:
   Metadata {
     options: undefined,
     internalRepr: Map { 'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array] } } }
```

Comment: Same is the case for me as well, guess DF issue

Comment: I also get this error suddenly

Comment: Facing the same issue since past 2 hours. I have a client deadline today. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: May be we can  post a support ticket in dialogflow group in google support. And in github too.

Comment: @SudheeshR Already raised ticket in support group.

Comment: @PriteshKanthaliya great! I think it's working properly now.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure this is something wrong with dialogflow service. This is not the first time dialogflow facing some issues.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure something is wrong with one of their servers behind the load balancer. If you try multiple times, sometimes a request can get through. But it should most definitely be a dialogflow api server issue.

Comment: yes, getting responses if we try multiple times. Seems like something broken at dialogflow server.

Answer (score 0):

It was issue from Dialogflow side, their technical team worked on it and resolved it. However they did not tell exactly what was the actual issue.

There is [github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/issues/140) as well for the same.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's a rate limit of the Dialogflow API? I had the same error with a python script, after a few minutes it worked fine...
Says [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas) there is a limit for 60 requests per minute.

Comment: no, if you try multiple times you'll get response (*if you're lucky :-) ).

Comment: That's what I was saying, if there are too many requests in a short time, this error appears, no?

Comment: nope. even if we cross the 60 request per minute mark, we are getting response from DF. But it's working fine now.